# Why is EcoRI supplied with a unique buffer when it is allegedly 100% active in universal buffers?

Tags: molecular-biology, experimental-design, restriction-enzymes, materials

Thermo packages a unique buffer with EcoRI:

> - 50 mM Tris-HCl (pH 7.5)
> - 10 mM MgCl<sub>2</sub>
> - 100 mM NaCl
> - 0.02% Triton X-100
> - 0.1 mg/mL BSA

However, they also list their EcoRI enzyme as 100% active in Buffer O with no indicated star activity:

> - 50 mM Tris-HCl (pH 7.5 at 37°C)
> - 10 mM MgCl<sub>2</sub>
> - 100 mM NaCl
> - 0.1 mg/ml BSA

The same is true of 2X Tango:

> - 66 mM Tris-acetate (pH 7.9 at 37°C)
> - 20 mM magnesium acetate
> - 132 mM potassium acetate
> - 0.2 mg/ml BSA

Is there a reason one would preferably use the unique buffer over a universal one? Given that buffer compatibility is a major selling point for restriction enzymes, why would they continue to supply a unique buffer?

Comment: I look forward to the explanation for why this is a homework question...

Comment: Me too. I think this is a legitimate question. And an interesting one, too.

Comment: Interestingly for the Fast Digest system an universal buffer (green) is recommended.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. Are the Fast Digest enzymes engineered? I know NEB offers two EcoRI enzymes: regular and high fidelity. The latter is engineered for high activity in universal buffers. For Thermo, their "regular" EcoRI is apparently active in multiple universal buffers and is actually supplied with the unique buffer *and* Tango universal.

Comment: The composition of the fast digest buffers is not disclosed...I found one paper, which links the presence of Triton X-100 to a lower star activity, but they use much higher concentration, see [here](http://www.biotechniques.com/multimedia/archive/00010/99275st02_10026a.pdf).

Comment: I have a suspicion that the unique buffer might be technically the best but the enzyme is also *almost* fully active in the universal buffers and displays neglible star activity so they just list it as 100% active for simplicity's sake. I may write their technical support a short email to see if they can clarify.

Comment: If you do, please let us know when you get an answer that tells us anything (although I doubt it).

Comment: @Chris I will do.

Comment: I'd +1 your thought to ask their technical support; they probably have more technical data than most users would, most users are probably just going to say "oh yeah it worked fine for me in _____ buffer" without having a quantitative comparison to a dozen buffer compositions. I don't use restriction enzymes in my work but I'm guessing they might supply it with the Triton X to get it into solution when it could be adhered to the supplying vessel. The other buffers might work fine but with a little Triton X they are confident it will all be in solution and therefore results more reliable.

Comment: @canadianer I expect that you get 100% of the listed units as activity in all buffers, but that you can get more activity if you use the unique buffer. Who might need this? No clue...

Comment: @Chris In case you're interested, I contacted tech support and updated the answer below. Apparently it may show star activity in the universal buffers despite this not being listed.

Comment: @canadianer Cool thanks. I find this interesting, and the suspicion it might have to do with star activity is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activity toward the desired substrate sequence is not the only concern in evaluating a restriction enzyme buffer system. In addition, you need to be concerned about so-called "[star activity](https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/usage-guidelines/star-activity)", or activity of the enzyme toward other, non-desired nucleotide sequences.

For example, NEB supplies an enzyme-specific buffer for it's standard [EcoRI](https://www.neb.com/products/r0101-ecori), even though it lists 100% activity in buffer #2 of NEB's standard buffer series. But at the very bottom of the page, there's this note: *"May exhibit star activity in NEBuffer 2.1 or CutSmart Buffer."*

[Promega](https://www.promega.com/products/cloning-and-dna-markers/restriction-enzymes/ecori/) has a similar warning about it's "MULTI-CORE" buffer - even though EcoRI has 100% activity in that buffer. The MULTI-CORE buffer is not recommended due to star activity - cleavage at non-standard sites.

It's a little hidden on the product data sheet, but [Thermo Scientific](https://tools.thermofisher.com/content/sfs/manuals/MAN0012089_EcoRI_10_UuL_5000U_UG.pdf) does have a mention of star activity in the standard "Tango" buffer, and mentions star activity with overdigestion in the standard "R" buffer. There's no warning about buffer "O", but given EcoRI's propensity toward star activity, I'm guessing this is part of why they recommend a unique buffer for routine usage. Given how frequently EcoRI is used in molecular biology, it's worth using a custom buffer to get the star activity as low as possible.

---

From canadianer: I contacted Thermo's technical support. Despite the fact that star activity is not listed as a concern for either 2X Tango or Buffer O in the product data for EcoRI, they say that it may actually show some star activity in these universal buffers which is why they continue to supply the unique buffer for this enzyme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should've clarified in my question that Thermo does not indicate star activity for both Buffer O and 2X Tango. As I mentioned in the comments, I suspect you may be right that star activity is minimized in the unique buffer whereas there may be some higher degree (negligible?) in the universal buffers.